# How to extract out-of-page contents in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf

A scientific publisher has rendered a PDF version of its journal so that the text bodies of articles are not in the visible parts of the page. The margin on the left-hand side is quite large, and the text body will overflow to the right-hand side of the page, and will end up on the non-visible part of the page.

The overflowed part can be selected and copied as text - so it is part of the document - but all the PDF viewers I have tried (Apple Preview, Google Chrome, Adobe Reader) will not show the content outside the page boundaries.

Is there a way to render all the visible and non-visible content on a larger canvas (say, if the original PDF is A4, the target would be A3) or otherwise view the PDF file as intended? Copying and pasting the text body to a text editor is not acceptable, since the figures and non-Latin script will not appear correctly in the copy target.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what is wrong:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sure. I don't have good enough reputation to post images, but I have included a link. The publisher has fixed the PDF, but resolving this generally could be useful...

Comment: I'd patch the PDF with the correct page dimensions, then it should work with all readers. Finding a reader that allows you to ignore the page dimensions as specified in the PDF file is hit-or-miss. PDF files are basically (compressed) text, so after uncompressing (e.g. with `mutool`) you can change it in any text editor.